# python requests via session proxy

Tags: python, session, proxy, web-crawler

I am having a **use case** to get data from a specific site which needs to have requests via **session** every time. I have created the session in python and also cookies are set which contain my logged in details.

I am currently hosting my script on a **data center** but the account is getting blocked. I am thinking of requesting the data via proxy but still feel that if my session is created from a different machine and proxy is used to get data via session then what are the chances that the proxy ip is going to be **black-listed?**

What are the possible solutions here to cater this kind of problem.

Comment: Do you set 'User-Agent' header in your request? This might be an approach to avoid blocking

Comment: yes @DonnyFlaw its set

Answer (score 0):

Scenarios in Python Requests Session differs according to different regions,
Like in some countries some headers are not permitted in the request due to country laws.

> Since you are already making logged in session that means your user-agent and other headers are being set according to the response from login request.

**One of the solution might be using a proxy of a country which doesnot have strict rules of data extraction from that platfrom.**